# Bijection of a Generalised Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm halfway through a proof and I'm kind of stuck. The exercise is:

> Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in \{0, 1\}}$ be an **indexed system of sets**. Show that the map $$\mathbf f: \prod{\{A_i\}_{i\in \{0, 1\} }} \rightarrow A_0 \times A_1$$
> given by
> $$f(g) =(g(0), g(1))$$
> is a **Bijection**.

First we would like to show that $f$ is Injective: Consider two instances of input function $g$, e.g. $x$
and $y$ hence:
$$f(x)=f(y)$$
$$\therefore(x(0),x(1))=(y(0),y(1))$$
$$\therefore x(0) = y(0) \land x(1)=y(1) $$
$$\mathbf {dom}(x) = \mathbf{dom}(y) = \{0, 1\}$$
$$\therefore x(i) = y(i) \forall i \in \{0, 1\}$$
$\therefore f(g)$ is **Injective**. Is my reasoning correct so far?

Now to showing $f$ is Surjective, we consider the the **domain** and **codomain** of the mapping, namely, the **Generalised Cartesian Product of an Indexed Family of Sets**:
$$\prod{\{A_i\}_{i\in \{0, 1\} }}=\{\{(0,x_0 \in A_0),(1, x_1 \in A_1)\}\}$$
and the usual Cartesian Product:
$$A_0 \times A_1 =(x_0 \in A_0, x_1 \in A_1)$$
respectively.

It is trivial to see that the mapping given by $f$ is Surjective, as the two ordered pair elements of $f=(g(0),g(1))$ span over all $A_0$ and $A_1$ respectively and considering that $g$ could take any arbitrary function of $\mathbf {domain}$ $\{0, 1\}$by definition of the **Generalised Cartesian Product of an Indexed Family of Sets**. But how do I write this formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of injectivity is correct, though I would add one more line concluding that $x=y$. For the proof of surjectivity, let $\langle a_0,a_1\rangle\in A_0\times A_1$ be arbitrary; then $a_0\in A_0$ and $a_1\in A_1$. Define

$$x:\{0,1\}\to A_0\cup A_1:\begin{cases}
0\mapsto a_0\\
1\mapsto a_1\;;
\end{cases}$$

then $f(x)=\langle x(0),x(1)\rangle=\langle a_0,a_1\rangle$, so $f$ is surjective.